# Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): Never ends

Tags: python, anaconda, package, upgrade, conda

I'm trying to upgrade my anaconda python from `2.7` to `3.6`, however when I run:

`conda install python=3.6`

It stays forever in:

`Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): |`

Then, I tried updating anaconda with `conda update conda` and also with `conda update anaconda` thinking it was a problem of the version, but it's the same, it stays forever collecting the package metadata and never ends and doesn't give me any error. What can I do?

My version is `anaconda 4.7.12`.